# Faster alternative to git lfs clone from remote GitHub repositories?

Tags: git, performance, github, git-clone, git-lfs

### Objective

I have a remote [GitHub repositories](https://github.com/PackardChan/chk2019-blocking-extreme), which uses git-lfs to hold large binary files.

- I want others to be able to quickly download my code and data.
- If speed can be enhanced, I don't expect others to necessarily version control their copies of the repository with git.
- Preferably, I want to know the reason of being slow or being fast.

### Baseline approach (`git lfs clone`)

As a test of how others will download my repository, I ran the following command on a high performance login node (with 72 Intel Xeon CPUs) on a Linux cluster, using a gpfs disk, and with these versions of git and git-lfs.

- git version 2.10.2
- git-lfs/2.3.4 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.9.1; git d2f6752f)

```
$ time git lfs clone --progress git@github.com:PackardChan/chk2019-blocking-extreme.git
Cloning into 'chk2019-blocking-extreme'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 138, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (138/138), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (114/114), done.
remote: Total 138 (delta 20), reused 138 (delta 20), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (138/138), 148.16 MiB | 36.59 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (20/20), done.
Git LFS: (64 of 64 files) 7.29 GB / 7.29 GB                                                              

real    4m51.156s
user    7m14.044s
sys 0m28.360s
```

This took near 5 minutes even in a high performance node. And I noticed that the last line of output reaches the total of 7.29GB only in 36 seconds. The rest of the time is running `git update-index -q --refresh --stdin` (from what I learn from `top -c` command).

I therefore believe the performance can be substantially improved if update-index can be skipped. As mentioned in "Objectives", if speed can be improved, I don't mind giving up git version control.

### Other unsuccessful attempts

1. svn export

Inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18324428/9382524), I tried:

```
time svn export https://github.com/PackardChan/chk2019-blocking-extreme/trunk z4svn
```

But the lfs files are not correctly downloaded. This is also reported [here](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Is-git-LFS-compatible-with-SVN-client-support-on-GitHub/m-p/5346/highlight/true#M1737).

2. git archive

However, [GitHub doesn't support git-archive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43079188/9382524).

3. --depth=1

I tried, it didn't perform better. This is understandable as my repository only has one commit.

I am rather new to git. So, am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. It turns out that the problem is I didn't run `git lfs install` to setup `~/.gitconfig`.

> git lfs install [options]
>
> Perform the following actions to ensure that Git LFS is setup
>   properly:
>
> - Set up the clean and smudge filters under the name "lfs" in the global Git   config.
> - Install a pre-push hook to run git lfs pre-push for the current repository,   if run from inside one. If "core.hooksPath" is
>     configured in any Git   configuration (and supported, i.e., the
>     installed Git version is at least
>     2.9.0), then the pre-push hook will be installed to that directory instead.

After that, I have 4 more lines of configuration reported from `git config --list`.

```
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
```

Now the same command of `time git lfs clone --progress git@github.com:PackardChan/chk2019-blocking-extreme.git` takes only around 1 minute.