# How to make 'svn export' less verbose?

Tags: svn, output, verbose, verbosity, svn-export

I'm cloning just the files of a Git repo (so without history or the `.git` folder) using `svn export https://github.com/user/repo/trunk` as per [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18324428/16886597). Sadly, Git archive [is disabled on GitHub](https://twitter.com/GitHubHelp/status/322818593748303873), which is why I didn't use that.

However, `svn archive` prints every single file in the repo out when it does this, which is rather annoying given that my repo isn't small. How can I make `svn export` only print something if there is a problem, as opposed to for every file in the repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there is a `--quiet` argument. For example this won't print anything.

```
$ svn export --quiet https://github.com/user/repo/trunk
```

---

If anyone is wondering, I figured this out my doing:

```
$ svn help
```

I didn't read that at first because I mostly use Git, and [the manpage seemed to be unhelpful](https://linux.die.net/man/1/svn), which is where I'd usually look..

Comment: You need to check `svn help` and SVNBook at https://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/index.html